# Installing HHVM error

Tags: fastcgi, ubuntu-14.04, hhvm

I am trying to configure my server running on Ubuntu 14.04 to use HHVM. I've had no issues actually installing it but getting it to run is a another story. I tried the command recommended by Sara Golemon and received the below error from the following command:

`hhvm --mode server -vServer.Type=fastcgi -vServer.Port=9000`

**Error:**

```
mapping self...
mapping self took 0'00" (850613 us) wall time
loading static content...
loading static content took 0'00" (0 us) wall time
WARNING: Logging before InitGoogleLogging() is written to STDERR
E1002 18:00:48.646344 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
shutting down old HPHP server by /stop command
E1002 18:00:49.659973 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:50.673045 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:51.686043 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:52.699100 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:53.712280 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:54.725271 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:55.738396 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:56.751373 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:57.764286 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:58.777184 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:00:59.790115 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:00.803050 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:01.815943 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:02.829088 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:03.842411 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:04.855499 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:05.868418 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:06.881392 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:07.894340 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:08.907320 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:09.920305 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:10.933312 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:11.946321 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:12.959223 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:13.972154 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:14.985043 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:15.997900 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:17.010850 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:18.023761 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:19.036653 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:20.049598 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:21.062446 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:22.075346 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:23.088186 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:24.101089 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:25.114043 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:26.127012 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:27.139890 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:28.152781 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:29.165693 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:30.178823 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:31.191797 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:32.204766 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:33.217674 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:34.230551 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:35.243446 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:36.256441 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:37.269491 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:38.282589 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:39.295550 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:40.308421 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:41.321308 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:42.334256 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:43.347374 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:44.360455 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:45.373364 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:46.386343 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:47.399708 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:48.412644 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
E1002 18:01:49.425597 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
shutting down old HPHP server by pid file
Unable to read pid file www.pid for any meaningful pid
E1002 18:01:50.425833 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
Unable to read pid file www.pid for any meaningful pid
E1002 18:01:51.426054 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
Unable to read pid file www.pid for any meaningful pid
E1002 18:01:52.426269 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
Unable to read pid file www.pid for any meaningful pid
E1002 18:01:53.426494 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
Unable to read pid file www.pid for any meaningful pid
E1002 18:01:54.426728 12377 fastcgi-server.cpp:234] failed to bind to async server socket: [::]:9000: Address already in use
killing anything listening on port 9000
page server started
all servers started
```

Could anyone help me get this running correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That error is due to something else (perhaps php-fpm) already bound to port 9000. You can stop that process (something like `lsof -i | grep 9000` will tell you what it is), or use a different port (say, 9001) for HHVM.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try this method and get back to you if I have any issues (else I'll accept this answer). Just not sure what the `www.pid` is referencing.

Comment: It just seems to hang in terminal if I map it to port 9001.

Comment: It isn't hanging, it is running fine. Get your webserver to talk on port 9001 and you're golden.

Comment: @PaulTarjan Thanks. It appears it was running on port 9000 all along. I received the following from the command above: `hhvm    20266 www-data   16u  IPv6 2818306366      0t0  TCP *:9000 (LISTEN)`. Would this be correct?